# replace name with another keywork in qlikview script

Tags: replace, qlikview

Here i want to ask i have  this line in qlivkiew script in that  i want if there is "**abc**" or "**def**" available   then i want to consider these as **XYZ** and if not available then want to consider as "**NONE**"

```
if(if(Filename = '1.xlsx','DR', 
 if(Filename = '2.xlsx','DR',
 if(Filename = '3.xlsx','DRD', 
 if(Filename = '4.xlsx', 'DRD',
  ApplyMap('Segm',Ext.,RGro') = 'abc' or 'def', 'XYZ','None')  as In_Flag
```

how i modified this line according to my requirement

how i do that

any idea about this condition ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to repeat the test to use the *or*

```
if(if(Filename = '1.xlsx','DR', 
 if(Filename = '2.xlsx','DR',
  if(Filename = '3.xlsx','DRD', 
   if(Filename = '4.xlsx', 'DRD',
     ApplyMap('Segm',Ext.,RGro') = 'abc' or ApplyMap('Segm',Ext.,RGro') = 'def','XYZ','None')  as In_Flag
```

otherwise match can work

```
match(ApplyMap('Segm',Ext.,RGro'),'abc','xyz')
```